# Multisite overide current blog on load of Wordpress

Tags: multisite

I have been attempting to use `sunrise.php` to override the current multisite blog.  I have tried : `wp_cache_switch_to_blog( $blog_id )`  though this has no effect.

I have also tried everything in `https://paulund.co.uk/wordpress-multi-site-nested-paths` this tutorial, but I think this is out dated as it using `site` instead of the `blog`.

What is the correct way to override the current multisite blog?

Or could some point me in the direction of which core file handles setting ti?

Comment: you want to set the current blog prior of the load of what ? edit your question to give more details and examples about what you want to modify from the current functioning.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, I have updated the question to be clearer.